# Load JSON objects values and append them in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm working with filestack getting document info in a JSON object, but when I upload many files I want to append those JSON values in a textarea.

So, I have this in HTML:

```
<input id="ff" type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="myAPI" data-fp-mimetypes="application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" data-fp-container="modal" data-fp-multiple="true" data-fp-button-class="btn btn-primary l-align" data-fp-button-text="Upload" data-fp-services="SKYDRIVE,COMPUTER,URL,GOOGLE_DRIVE,GMAIL" data-fp-language="en">
<textarea id="json1" name="json1" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
<textarea id="json" name="json" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
```

And in JS:

```
for(var i=0;i<event.fpfiles.length;i++){
  var link = event.fpfiles[i].url;
  var idfile = link.substr(link.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
  var lcconvert = "https://process.filestackapi.com/output=docinfo:true/"+idfile;

  $("#json1").load(lcconvert);
  document.getElementById('json').value += 
  document.getElementById('json1').value;                   
}
```

I want to load every value in a textarea #json1 and append them in textarea #json but I only get the json value of the last file in #json1 like this:

```
<textarea id="json1" name="json1" cols="30" rows="2" style="display:none;">{"numpages":2,"dimensions":{"width":612,"height":792}}</textarea>
```

And I want this in #json:

```
<textarea id="json" name="json" cols="30" rows="2" style="display:none;">{"numpages":2,"dimensions":{"width":612,"height":792}}{"numpages":6,"dimensions":{"width":612,"height":792}}</textarea>
```

I would like some help

Comment: Don't use pure JS to add content, use `append()` instead and also you need to run the code that update `#json` when the load request is completed. It's async so the code won't stop and wait for `load()` to be completed using the callback. See jquery doc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GillesC comment I found the solution:

```
$("#json1").load(lcconvert, function(result){
    $("#json").append(result);
});
```

EDIT: Now I need to add also each url file so I made this:

```
$("#json1").load(lcconvert, function(result){
    $("#json").append(result + " "+link);
});
```

But I only get the last url file, like this in HTML:

```
<textarea id="json" name="json" cols="30" rows="2" style="display:none;">
{"numpages":2,"dimensions":{"width":612,"height":792}} <url_of_last_file>
{"numpages":6,"dimensions":{"width":595,"height":842}} <url_of_last_file>
</textarea>
```

And I want like this:

```
<textarea id="json" name="json" cols="30" rows="2" style="display:none;">
{"numpages":2,"dimensions":{"width":612,"height":792}} <url_of_file1>
{"numpages":6,"dimensions":{"width":595,"height":842}} <url_of_file2>
</textarea>
```

How can I change it?